# Как разрешить выполнение скриптов в WebBrowser, как в IE?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, internet-explorer, webbrowser

Я использую WebBrowser для просмотра некоторых веб-страниц, но я столкнулся с небольшой проблемой загрузки скриптов.

Код приведённый ниже не решил мою проблему, я хочу стабильной работы всех скриптов, а не их скрытия.

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Например, [Этот сайт](http://csgolounge.com) выполняется отлично в браузере Internet Explorer без каких-либо ошибок, но когда я открываю его в C# webBrowser, получаю 6-8 ошибок скриптов.

Первая из них:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что мне делать с этой проблемой?

Вот эта ссылка мне не помогла:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25142594/allowing-javascript-to-run-on-a-windows-form-web-browser

P.S: Я скопировал из окна ошибки ссылку на *.js , и вставил в IE браузер - ошибка, а в Хроме он открылся.

Comment: Русский язык не в моде?)

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык. С вопросами на английском вам на stackoverflow.com, а вы, прошу заметить, на ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ruSO

Comment: теперь на русском

Comment: по умолчанию _WebBrowser_ использует движок IE, то ли очень старой версии, то ли в режиме совместимости, поэтому с новыми скриптами он не сможет работать. попробуй вместо 3 версии jquery использовать 2. И ссылка из вопроса должна будет помочь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прежде всего извините за иностранный, раннее не имел дела с этом сайтом. Проблему все таки решил, кому интересно - [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333459/c-sharp-webbrowser-ajax-call/18333982#18333982). Теперь только разобраться с капчей осталось.

Answer (score -1):

Это не может не помогать:

```
webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Проверено 100500 раз.

Можете попробовать [Selenium](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/) там нет проблем со скриптами

Comment: Да ну? И как оно, по-вашему, может помочь?

Comment: Что именно? Скрытие ошибок уберет окно, а Selenium спокойно отработает скрипты(скорее всего)